# Mongodb find specific comment within array of objects in post collection

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, loops, findby

i store comments in `post` collection like this:

```
...
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    body: {
      type: String,
    },
    userId: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    likes: {
      type: Array,
      default: [],
    },
    img: {
      type: String,
      default: null,
    },
    comments: [
      {
        body: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        userId: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        postId: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
      },
      { timestamps: true },
    ],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
...
```

i created this `put` route to update comment:

```
app.put("/update-comment", (req, res) => {
  posts.updateComment(req, res);
});
```

`updateComment` function:

```
const updateComment = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const post = await Post.findById(req.body.postId);
    const comment = await post.comments.map((commentObj) => {
      return commentObj.find({ _id: req.body.commentId });
    });

    await comment.updateOne({ $set: req.body });
    res.status(200).json(comment);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
};
```

it finds the `post` by `postId` and simply loop the `comments` array to find the `comment` object with the `comment id` provided, i tried this route with `postman` providing the following `json` body:

```
{
    "postId":"6242a4c75bce78154824fc8f",
    "commentId":"6242ac32a61fd275ed13846b",
    "body":"my first comment updated"
}
```

but it doesn't work, it returns `500 internal error`, if i replaced the code with this:

```
  try {
    const post = await Post.findById(req.body.postId);
    const comment = post.comments;

    res.status(200).json(comment);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
```

it will indeed return the comments within that post as an array of objects, i don't know what's wrong, i made sure the `postId` and `commentId` provided by the json body is correct, what's the problem?